Rewrite rules en WordPress
Tengo un sitio con un custom permalink del tipo: /%location%/%postname%/
Que utilizo para mostrar posts para distintas localidades, location es un valor de una custom taxonomy que se asigna a cada post, entonces tengo un rewrite rule de este tipo:
function posts_rewrite_rules() {
  # Rule for posts with location: /location/postname
  add_rewrite_rule('^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?$', 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]', 'top', 'location_post');      
}

add_action('init', 'posts_rewrite_rules', 99, 0);

Para que wordpress puede devolver el post de una url del tipo dominio/location/postname y functiona de perlas, luego utilizo el archive page de WordPress para mostrar la lista de posts para esa localidad al acceder a dominio/location y tambien funciona bien, solo que ahora se requiere de alguna manera tambien devolver el post utilizando solo /postname, y no consigo que funcione, si agrego un rewrite rule del tipo:
function posts_rewrite_rules() {
  # Rule for posts with location: /location/postname
  add_rewrite_rule('^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?$', 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]', 'top', 'location_post');
      
  # Rule for posts without location: /postname
  add_rewrite_rule('^([^\/]+)/?$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&post_type=post', 'top', 'post');
}

add_action('init', 'posts_rewrite_rules', 99, 0);

Consigo devolver el post como si no hubiera un custom permalink, pero pierdo el archive page que utilizaba para listar los posts, porque ahora este me regresa un 404, al agregar una nueva rule para devolver de nuevo el location tengo el dilema que este me sobreescribe la regla del post, y termino caminando en circulos, yo se que el orden de como estan las reglas de rewrite se utiliza como una jerarquia de ejecucion por lo que el orden importa, el top o bottom de las opciones de la funcion tambien, pero no logro que funcione, por ejemplo si agrego:
function posts_rewrite_rules() {
  # Rule for posts with location: /location/postname
  add_rewrite_rule('^([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)/?$', 'index.php?location=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]', 'top', 'location_post');
      
  # Rule for posts without location: /postname
  add_rewrite_rule('^([^\/]+)/?$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&post_type=post', 'top', 'post');
  
  # Rule for only location: /location
  add_rewrite_rule('^([^\/]+)/?$', 'index.php?location=$matches[1]', 'top');  
}

add_action('init', 'posts_rewrite_rules', 99, 0);

Entonces el /postname ya no se devuelve, alguna idea de como resolverlo?

Bueno parece que de tanto intentar varias opciones encontre la que funciona, entonces haciendo un loop sobre los valores del custom taxonomy "location" pude asignar un rewrite rule basado en cada valor:
function locations_rewrite_rule() {
  $tax_slug = 'location';
  $terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => $tax_slug,
    'hide_empty' => false,
  ]);

  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    add_rewrite_rule('^' . $term->slug . '/?$', 'index.php?' . $tax_slug . '=' . $term->slug, 'top');
  }
}

add_action('init', 'locations_rewrite_rule', 98, 0);

